# Storage limit in raw and asset folder in android

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to store some video/audio files in raw folder of my application.

I don't know the storage limit of raw and asset folder.

Can anybody tell me how much data i can store in raw and asset folder.

And also what if i store bulk data in those folder, does it will affect to speed of execution or size of application to download from market?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each file in asset or raw needs to be under 1MB before compression. The total size of the APK can not exceed 50MB; if it does, you will need an expansion apk.

Comment: @323go: okk so i can add data in raw folder till then my apk size is below 50 MB. is it?

Comment: You can. It might be a better idea to load rich content separately, however. Makes for faster installs and updates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no limits on any resources now after Android2.3 release the new aapt.The limitation is caused by the older aapt for system peformance reason and should not happen now.

Comment: How do you know? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ahead there is so many problems  while you are loading the large size of files Directly from assets folder or raw folder.Some times it possible to cause vm budget out of error in android.

For solving your problem Place your resources in a server. Load them while very first installation of your application and store them in sd card .And access them into your application from your sd card...