# Cause: invalid block type [Android]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting this error whenever I try to build my project or try to release the apk. This error started appearing after updating my gradle to version 4.6-all. I couldn't find any solution and don't know what is causing this error. I also tried to disable instant run as well as invalidated cache and restarted the android studio but the problem remain the same. The only thing I understand is that the file I am using in my project (sp.dat) is causing this error. 
Thankyou in advance.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: invalid block type
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$onEach$1.invoke(_Sequences.kt:1260)
at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)
at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:153)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:633)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:663)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:654)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:140)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:115)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:32)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:401)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
... 33 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:106)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:166)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.StoredEntry.read(StoredEntry.java:291)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onZipEntryOutput(SigningExtension.java:251)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.access$400(SigningExtension.java:53)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1.lambda$added$0(SigningExtension.java:160)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2154)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.addToEntries(ZFile.java:1795)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntries(ZFile.java:1736)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1607)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.mergeFrom(ZFile.java:1959)
at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.writeZip(ApkZFileCreator.java:115)
at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateFiles(IncrementalPackager.java:206)
at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateAndroidResources(IncrementalPackager.java:255)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:695)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:515)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.lambda$doFullTaskAction$3(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:396)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:121)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:110)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:125)
... 52 more
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:292)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.access$200(SigningExtension.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1.lambda$beforeUpdate$2(SigningExtension.java:171)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2154)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:923)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1207)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:174)
    at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:216)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:332)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:704)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Still waiting to inspect output APK's res/raw/sp.dat
    at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.outputJarEntries(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:398)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:290)
    ... 72 more

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0" //        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.tzutalin.dlib-android-app:dlib:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    def room_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version" }
```

Comment: could you post your build.gradle file's content in your question.

Comment: @Aolphn edited the post to add the gradle

Comment: Did you add your proguard rules,your build.gradle configuration shows that you enable gropuard.

Comment: I'm notices that you got a v1 signature error,please check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129414/android-studio-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-generate-v1-signature)

Comment: The link that you have given suggests that we delete the file. We can not do that as it is the main part of our application.

Comment: use gradlew --stack assemble to check details of error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you did. Turns out, there is a 1 MB size limit on the files you can use [as assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995756/storage-limit-in-raw-and-asset-folder-in-android).

Your sp.dat is likely larger than 1 MB.