# Android `App-Specific` Storage access on the NDK(C/C++) code

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-storage

Due to [1MB limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995756/storage-limit-in-raw-and-asset-folder-in-android) on `assets` and `raw`, i cannot keep a binary files.

On the Java side we have something like **App-specific** storage as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), there is not file size limit too.

Is this storage available on NDK side too? How can access a file in the C/C++(NDK) space?

Comment: Retrieve the path in Java/Kotlin, pass it to your native code, then use whatever file I/O API you normally use in your C or C++ code.

Comment: @Michael is it something like `String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();` and the output i get is following `/data/user/0/com.demo.app/files`

Comment: Yeah, `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()` ought to work.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Michael. Can you please put this as an answer? I too verified it and it works.